# Ruby function to check if a number is divisible by five and is even

Tags: ruby

```
def is_even?(n)
  remainder_when_divided_by_2 = n % 2

  if remainder_when_divided_by_2 == 0
    return true
  else
    return false
  end
end

def is_odd?(n)
  return ! is_even?(n)
end

puts "1 is_even? #{is_even?(1)} - is_odd? #{is_odd?(1)}"
puts "2 is_even? #{is_even?(2)} - is_odd? #{is_odd?(2)}"
puts "3 is_even? #{is_even?(3)} - is_odd? #{is_odd?(3)}"
puts "4 is_even? #{is_even?(4)} - is_odd? #{is_odd?(4)}"
puts "5 is_even? #{is_even?(5)} - is_odd? #{is_odd?(5)}"
puts "6 is_even? #{is_even?(6)} - is_odd? #{is_odd?(6)}"

def is_even_and_divisible_by_five?(n)
  remainder_when_divided_by_five = n % 5

  if (remainder_when_divided_by_five == 0) && (is_even?(n) == true)
    return true
  else
    return false
  end

end

puts "5 is_even_and_divisible_by_five? #{is_even_and_divisible_by_five?(5)}"
puts "10 is_even_and_divisible_by_five? #{is_even_and_divisible_by_five?(10)}"
puts "15 is_even_and_divisible_by_five? #{is_even_and_divisible_by_five?(15)}"
puts "20 is_even_and_divisible_by_five? #{is_even_and_divisible_by_five?(20)}"
puts "25 is_even_and_divisible_by_five? #{is_even_and_divisible_by_five?(25)}"
puts "30 is_even_and_divisible_by_five? #{is_even_and_divisible_by_five?(30)}"
```

The problem was I had not called the method is_even_and_divisible_by_five in the puts commands at the bottom of the code. I called it is_even_and_divisble_by_5.  Then in the if statement in the is_even_and_divisble_by_five method, I left of the (n) arguement from Is_even.  Thank you all very much!

Comment: I place your code to irb and got `undefined method 'is_even?' for main:Object`. It looks like you forgot to define it :)

Comment: Can you paste your whole script? In ruby, you need to define methods *before* you use them, so if your method definitions appear at the end of your script then that won't work. Also, have you defined the method `is_even?`

Comment: I think your condition should be `(remainder_when_divided_by_five == 0) && n.even?`

Comment: divisible by 5 and even == divisible by 10

Comment: Cannot be reproduced.

Comment: You are getting an error for a method that doesn't get called in your code. Also please post the definition of is_even?

Comment: You could also write `n.to_s[-1]=='0'`. :-)

Comment: It looks as though may you have edited your question so that it no longer  shows the problem.  If that's so, then you should know that SO doesn't work like that.  Having the original problem shown in the question is necessary for the answers to make sense, and to help others in the future who may have a similar problem.  For next time, instead of editing the question, please add an answer (yes, you can answer your own question) that explains how you fixed the problem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Even (divisible by two) and divisible by five also means "divisible by ten":

```
def is_even_and_divisible_by_five?(n)
  n % 10 == 0
end
```

Comment: Very true, I didn't think about that. Feel silly now, thank you very much for the help

Answer (score 5):

You called

```
 is_even_and_divisible_by_5?
```

instead of

```
 is_even_and_divisible_by_five?
```

Also is_even? function is undefined. I guess there was some mistake made with its defining or maybe even not-defining. So maybe when you defined `is_even_and_divisible_by_five?(n)` function there were some other errors and It was not defined too. Plus I think here is much easier solution:

```
def is_even_and_divisible_by_five?(n)
  n % 5 == 0 && n.even?
end
```

In Ruby You don't have to use return all the time. You should use it quite rarely. The reason is ruby functions return last calculated value by default. And nearly everything is returning value in ruby, even blocks and If-Else statements. If you open irb console and try to do some code, for example:

```
a = 5
=> 5
```

Second line is what first line returns. You can do some experiments like this by your own with any type of conditions you like.

Comment: The `if (x) true else false` pattern needs to die. Nice work fixing this.

Comment: That's what was wrong, I called is_even_and_divisible_by_5 and not ..._five like it should have been. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

The name of your method is `is_even_and_divisible_by_five?`, not `is_even_and_divisible_by_5?`.

Answer (score 2):

is_even? is not defined by itself
Here a shorter version of your method

```
def is_even_and_divisible_by_five? n
  0 == n % 5 + n % 2 
end
```

Comment: Or even shorter: `n % 10 == 0`

Comment: Thank you! I don't know what I'd do without all the help I get here