# Method in ruby which evaluates whether an number is evenly divisible

Tags: ruby

Is there a core method which implements something like this `x%y == 0` ?

I suppose ideally it would be something like such `10.is_evenly_divisble_by?(5)`

Comment: No, there is not. Example of custom function can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29631381/1566187).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to wrap everything in functions you can use http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Numeric.html#method-i-modulo

```
def evenly_dividable(num)
  modulo(num).zero?
end
```

Comment: Shouldn't `modulo` be called on a numeric receiver? ...something like `x.modulo(y).zero?`

Comment: module is a function in Numeric, so you can add:

     class Numeric
         def evenly_dividable?(num)
            modulo(num).zero?
         end
     end
in some file you're loading at application startup.
In this case you can call 5.evenly_dividable?(3)

As for 5.modulo(3).zero? - it can be used too.

Comment: @WandMaker In this case, the `x` is `self`.

Comment: @IgorPavlov I missed to notice that solution is suggesting to monkey patch the `Numeric` class